# how to add data in database from startup.cs in mvc

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, database, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add data into a user defined table i.e. gender table. I am adding roles from code but role table is builtin in project. Below here is my code, I am creating roles in builtin table by code in startup.cs but how can I add data in user defined table.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    ConfigureAuth(app);
    CreateRolesandUsers();
}

private void CreateRolesandUsers()
{
    ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();

    var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(context));
    var UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context));

    // In Startup I am creating first Admin Role and creating a default Admin User     
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Admin"))
    {
        // first we create Admin role
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Admin";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    //creating Creating Manager role
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Manager"))
    {                
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Manager";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    //creating Creating Judge role
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Judge"))
    {
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Judge";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    //creating Creating Police role
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Police"))
    {
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Police";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }

    //creating Creating Jailer role
    if (!roleManager.RoleExists("Jailer"))
    {
        var role = new IdentityRole();
        role.Name = "Jailer";
        roleManager.Create(role);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's not data that's managed by framework scaffolding, such as the roles are, then I imagine you'd just have to manually invoke your data operations just as you would anywhere else in the application.

Comment: You would, and that is also not really the optimal approach. If you have a bunch of static data that needs to be in a database, why don't you just put that data in the database through a means that doesn't involve recompiling your app every time you need to populate a table? It could literally be as simple as having a proc that is like usp_StaticData_Populate or such as that, and simply having the app invoke it as needed. Then you update the proc and not the app. There are other similar approaches that seem better to me than having to refactor Startup.cs all the time.